# COM interop, creating .net com and consuming in .net

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I have an assembly which exposes com interface:

```
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("C92A5F13-088F-4776-A967-42A60EFAFC29")]  
  public interface ITestInterface
  {
    byte[] AddItem(string label, byte[] array);
  }
```

And implementation:

```
  [ComVisible(true)]
  [Guid("C35C9235-3377-44A7-AC9E-7FCC24EF71D0")]    
  public class Test : ITestInterface
  {
    public byte[] AddItem(string label, byte[] array)
    {
      return null;//irrelevant
    }
  }
```

That com is published in manifest of the assembly.

Now in the client side (.net), I have an interface:

```
  public interface ITestInterface
  {
    byte[] AddItem(string label, byte[] array);
  }
```

and try to activate it:

```
Type adapter = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Test.Test");                 
object adapterObj = Activator.CreateInstance(adapter);

ITestInterface myClassAdapter = (ITestInterface)adapterObj;
```

On the last line I get exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Test.Test' to type 'Test.ITest'.'
```

What's wrong with my "client" interface. What should I change?

Comment: The `ITestInterface` of the client assembly ist not the same as `ITestInterface` of the COM assembly, despite its equal name. You have to add a reference to the original COM assembly in your client assembly, and use its interface. If you don't expose the interface to other languages, there is no benefit in making it visible as COM object.

Comment: .NET type identity includes not just the namespace+type identifier name but also the assembly it came from.  So as-is, the client interface declaration is never compatible with the server interface and the cast must always fail.  The [type equivalence feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/type-equivalence-and-embedded-interop-types) in .NET 4.0+ can solve your problem, but the [Guid] must be the same.  Do note that you don't actually use COM, the CLR is not easily fooled, so it is not an appropriate way to test anything.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I was following this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/204406/How-To-Use-a-NET-Based-DLL-From-NET-Based-Appl?msg=5711495#xx5711495xx alas, the author didn't publish the client interface ...

Comment: @HansPassant Why do you mean i don't use com?

Comment: Maybe you just want to use the COM assembly by your client assembly? If so, you can just go to the "solution explorer" in your client assembly, navigate to YourProject/References and add the required assembly. There is no need for a COM interface to use classes/interfaces of another .net assembly.

Comment: I want to use .net 4.0 assembly as a com in my ,.net 3.5 assembly. That's why I cannot reference assembly from the higher framework ...